# Python OpenCV video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) returns 0.0 FPS

Tags: python, opencv, mp4, frame-rate

This is my video

[image]

This is the script to find fps:

```
import cv2
if __name__ == '__main__' :

    video = cv2.VideoCapture("test.mp4");

    # Find OpenCV version
    (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

    if int(major_ver)  < 3 :
        fps = video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print "Frames per second using video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS): {0}".format(fps)
    else :
        fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print "Frames per second using video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) : {0}".format(fps)

    video.release();
```

This is the output of the script for this video:
`Frames per second using video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) : 0.0`

Why is it returning 0.0? The FPS is 14.0

Comment: did you check opencv actually opened the file? (with `video.isOpened()`)

Comment: @api55 you are right it didn't, it returns `False`. Why is that?

Comment: well, it didn't open it, you can try with `video.open("test.mp4")` try, to put the full path just in case... if not try another video (to discard a codec problem)

Comment: It was actually because opencv was not installed via pip (I have no idea how it was being importing, it's my first time using it). So after doing `pip-install python-opencv`, it worked like a charm.

Comment: That just explains what was the problem in the first place, 
when you install opencv with pip it brings its own backends (ffmpeg)
so I think the problem was that your first opencv backend was broken

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Performing `pip install python-opencv` fixed the problem and the FPS is correctly detected.

EDIT: tested with python 3.8 and indeed it is `pip install opencv-python`. Cannot remember two years ago what python I was using.

EDIT November 2022: please also check [Perry's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74475646/1238675), if you are using a newer `opencv-python` version

Comment: When I try this on Windows 10, I get three rows of output: `Collecting python-opencv`, `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-opencv (from versions: none)` and
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-opencv`

Comment: Actually it should be `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: On a Google Colab Notebook, I had to use `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall opencv-python`

Answer (score 7):

The recent versions of opencv-python will give an error called `AttributeError` because `cv2` doesn't have any attribute named `cv`.

Instead use the following

```py
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('some_video.avi')
fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

print(f"{fps} frames per second")
```

This will give the `frames per second` value