# OpenCV 4.1.1.26 reports 90000.0 fps for a 25fps RTSP stream

Tags: opencv

I have an RTP/RTSP stream that's running at 25fps, as verified by `ffprobe -i <URI>`. Also, VLC plays back the RTSP stream at a real-time rate, but doesn't show me the FPS in the **Media Information** window.

However, when I use OpenCV 4.1.1.26 to retrieve the input stream's frame rate, it is giving me a response of `90000.0`.

**Question**: How can I use OpenCV to probe for the correct frame rate of the RTSP stream? What would cause it to report `90000.0` instead of `25`?

Here's my Python function to retrieve the frame rate:

```
import cv2
vid : cv2.VideoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.1.10/cam1/mpeg4')

def get_framerate(video: cv2.VideoCapture):
    fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print('FPS is {0}'.format(fps))

get_framerate(vid)
```

- MacOS Catalina
- Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you somehow. It is a simple calculator that takes `cont` captures and measure the beginning and the ending time. Then with the rule of three, i converted it to `fps`.

Related to you second question i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025795/python-opencv-video-getcv2-cap-prop-fps-returns-0-0-fps) that it could be due to bad installation. Also, you can check that your camera is working properly by printing `ret` variable. If it is `true` then you should be able to see the fps, if it is `false` then you can have an unpredictable result.

`cv2.imshow()` and `key = cv2.waitKey(1)` should be commented as it adds ping/delay resulting in bad measurement.

---

I post this as a comment because i do not have enough reputation points.

```
img = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.1.10/cam1/mpeg4')

while True:

    if cont == 50:
        a = datetime.now() - start 
        b = (a.seconds * 10e6 + a.microseconds)
        print((a.seconds * 10e6 + a.microseconds), "fps = ", (50 * 10e6)/ b)
        break


    ret, frame = img.read()

    # Comment for best test
    cv2.imshow('fer', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

    cont+=1

img.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```